# Transforming Spark dataframe into a Spark DenseMatrix for operations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I've looked all over the internet, and couldn't find how to simply transform a dataframe in spark into a matrix so I can do matrix operations on it.

How can I simply achieve this in Spark 2?

Answer (score 2):

Understand that DenseMatrix in spark creates a local, not a distributed matrix and will put everything in single node. A densematrix can be created in the following way

```
# Constructor : DenseMatrix(numRows, numCols, values)
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Matrix, Matrices
dm2 = Matrices.dense(3, 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

However you have to pass all your rows into a single big list which defeats the purpose of using spark at all.

In case you were looking for just doing matrix operations on your dataframe and are not hung up on the DenseMatrix format, I suggest you use the `RowMatrix` constructor in `pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed`

It is pretty simple to convert an rdd to a densematrix as shown below

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix

# Create an RDD of vectors.
rows = sc.parallelize([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])

# Create a RowMatrix from an RDD of vectors.
mat = RowMatrix(rows)

# Get its size.
m = mat.numRows()  # 4
n = mat.numCols()  # 3
```

In case of a dataframe you can simply pass on `df.rdd` to the RowMatrix constructor. More details about different methods of RowMatrix can be found at the following link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix